# How to do wordcount in a DataSet which one column is of array<string> type in Java Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset, two columns:

```
queryTermCounts         queryTerms
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...]   [hello, world, spark, hello, hello...]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...]   [eat, fish, cat, cat, fish...]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...]   [today, sun, sun, cloud, hello...]
```

queryTerms is the words in the document after word segmentation, queryTermCounts corresponds to the number of occurrences of words in queryTerms, but all are 1.

I hope to make statistics on the words in queryTerms again, count the words in queryTerms and put the corresponding count in querytermCounts, looks like:

```
queryTermCounts         queryTerms
[3, 1, 1 ...]       [hello, world, spark ...]
[2, 2, 1 ...]       [fish, cat, eat ...]
[2, 1, 1, 1 ...]    [sun, today, cloud, hello...]
```

I try to use :

```java
Dataset<Row> words = data.select(functions.explode(functions.split(data.col("queryTerms"), ",\\s*")).as("word"));

Dataset<Row> wordCounts = words.join(input, functions.array_contains(functions.split(input.col("queryTerms"), ",\\s*"), words.col("word")))
                .groupBy("word")
                .agg(functions.sum("queryTermCounts").as("count"));
```

It work collect on String, but doesn't worked on `array<string>` type, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hi Nico, I've posted an answer, let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - Using just one column `queryTerms` as discussed in comments:

Window is to make sure both lists are in order, as [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) doesn't guarantee order.

Java:

```
WindowSpec w = Window.orderBy(functions.col("queryTerms")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding(), Window.unboundedFollowing());

df.select("queryTerms")
  .withColumn("queryTerms", functions.explode(functions.col("queryTerms")))
  .groupBy("queryTerms")
  .agg(functions.count("queryTerms").alias("queryTermCounts"))
  .select(functions.collect_list("queryTerms").over(w).alias("queryTerms"), functions.collect_list("queryTermCounts").over(w).alias("queryTermCounts"))
  .select(functions.first("queryTerms").alias("queryTerms"), functions.first("queryTermCounts").alias("queryTerms"))
  .show(false);
```

PySpark:

```
w=Window.orderBy(F.col("queryTerms")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing);

df.select("queryTerms")\
 .withColumn("queryTerms", F.explode("queryTerms"))\
 .groupBy("queryTerms")\
 .agg(F.count("queryTerms").alias("queryTermCounts"))\
 .select(F.collect_list("queryTerms").over(w).alias("queryTerms"), F.collect_list("queryTermCounts").over(w).alias("queryTermCounts"))\
 .select(F.first("queryTerms").alias("queryTerms"), F.first("queryTermCounts").alias("queryTerms"))\
 .show(truncate=False)
```

**Update - In Java:**

```
     df
        .withColumn("asStruct", functions.arrays_zip(functions.col("queryTermCounts"), functions.col("queryTerms")))
        .withColumn("asStruct", functions.explode(functions.col("asStruct")))
        .select(functions.col("asStruct.*"))
        .groupBy("queryTerms")
        .agg(functions.sum("queryTermCounts").alias("queryTermCounts"))
        .withColumn("queryTermCounts", functions.collect_list("queryTermCounts").over(Window.orderBy("queryTerms")))
        .withColumn("queryTerms", functions.collect_list("queryTerms").over(Window.orderBy("queryTerms")))
        .withColumn("mx", functions.max(functions.size(functions.col("queryTerms"))).over(Window.orderBy(functions.lit("dummy"))))
        .filter(functions.size(functions.col("queryTerms")).equalTo(functions.col("mx")))
        .drop("mx")
        .show(false);
```

In Pyspark this would work (will post Java equivalent soon):

```
df.withColumn('asStruct', F.arrays_zip('queryTermCounts', 'queryTerms'))\
.withColumn('asStruct', F.explode('asStruct'))\
.select(F.col('asStruct.*'))\
.groupBy("queryTerms")\
.agg(F.sum("queryTermCounts").alias("queryTermCounts"))\
.withColumn("queryTermCounts", F.collect_list("queryTermCounts").over(Window.orderBy("queryTerms")))\
.withColumn("queryTerms", F.collect_list("queryTerms").over(Window.orderBy("queryTerms")))\
.withColumn("mx", F.max(F.size("queryTerms")).over(Window.orderBy(F.lit("dummy"))))\
.filter(F.size("queryTerms")==F.col("mx"))\
.drop("mx")\
.show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, it work on small data, but when I try big data, I have OutOfMemory errror. If i only use queryTerms to calculate and store result in a new column, will this solved?

Comment: and when I have a lot of line, it combine them as one line, just like [world, spark, hello, eat, cat, fish, today, sun, cloud] | [1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]

Comment: I didn't got your point two, but for #1 yes you can use `queryTerms` only if you want I can help you with the same. Whether or not OOM will occur, depends on the size, but a single column may reduce data so you can give it a try.

Comment: Added new solution, please check and let me know

Comment: thank you for your help! I didn't use Window, so the order is wrong, really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I have only used the array functions and map to get the result.

**PySpark**

```
data = [
    [['hello', 'world', 'spark', 'hello', 'hello']],
    [['eat', 'fish', 'cat', 'cat', 'fish']],
    [['today', 'sun', 'sun', 'cloud', 'hello']]
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['queryTerms'])

df.withColumn('countMap', f.aggregate(
    'queryTerms',
    f.create_map().cast('map<string, int>'),
    lambda acc, w: f.map_concat(f.map_filter(acc, lambda k, v: k != w), f.create_map(w, f.coalesce(acc[w] + f.lit(1), f.lit(1)))))
  ) \
  .withColumn('queryTerms', f.map_keys('countMap')) \
  .withColumn('queryTermsCount', f.map_values('countMap')) \
  .drop('countMap') \
  .show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+---------------+
|queryTerms                |queryTermsCount|
+--------------------------+---------------+
|[world, spark, hello]     |[1, 1, 3]      |
|[eat, cat, fish]          |[1, 2, 2]      |
|[today, sun, cloud, hello]|[1, 2, 1, 1]   |
+--------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: can you kindly provided a java version? there are a lot of different between them, I can't use create_map in java

Comment: it would be just a map

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html